# Имя параметра в C# Exception

Tags: c#, исключения, null

Я выдаю исключение если параметр у функции равен `null`, при этом в исключении имя параметра отображается не корректно (**Arg_ParamName_Name** вместо **arr**). Вопрос наверняка глупый, но я просто не могу понять что не так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ты наведи на красный крестик и прочитай текст, что всплывёт.... там написано что не так

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы не так поняли вопрос. Обновил, проверьте пожалуйста.

Comment: Пересоберите проект (rebuild)

Comment: @aepot Пересобрал, не помогло. Добавил еще скриншот, сообщение в конструкторе исключения устанавливается, а имя параметра не то.

Comment: Похоже на глюк дотнета или отладчика студии. Попробуйте поймать в catch и прочитать данные из исключения в коде

Comment: @aepot Вы правы. Если зайти в catch то там будет корректное имя параметра, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Обновите или переустановите студию.

Answer (score 0):

В конструкции `try {} catch {}` имя параметра отображается корректно, следовательно это баг студии.